# Rps game not working as expected from the shown website that I posted

Tags: python

ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
0 Wins,0 Losses, 0 Ties
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
P
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
S
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
Q
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
p
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
r
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
p
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
r
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
ss
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit

s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit

s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit

Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uits
s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit

s
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit

This is the result of the execution of what I put to create rps game, as you see, it does not not move on to next step.

```
import random, sys

print('ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS')

#These variables keep track of the number of wins, losses, and ties.
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

while True: # The main game loop.
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True: # The player input loop.
        print('Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == 'q':
            sys.exit() # Quit the program.
            if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove == 'p' or playerMove == 's':
                break # Break out of the player input loop.
            print('Type one of r, p, s, or q.')

# Display what the player chose:
if playerMove == 'r':
    print('ROCK versus...')
elif playerMove == 'p':
    print('PAPER versus...')
elif playerMove == 's':
    print('SCISSORS versus...')

# Display what the computer chose:
randomNumber = random.randiant(1,3)
if randomNumber == 1:
    computerMove = 'r'
    print('ROCK')
elif randomNumber == 2:
    computerMove = 'p'
    print('PAPER')
elif randomNumber == 3:
    computerMove = 's'
    print('SCISSORS')

# Display and record the win/loss/tie:
if playerMove == computerMove:
    print('It is a tie!')
    ties = ties + 1
elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 's':
        print('You win!')
        wins = wins + 1
elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 'r':
        print('You win!')
        wins = wins + 1
elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'p':
        print('You win!')
        wins = wins + 1
elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 'p':
        print('You lose!')
        losses = losses + 1
elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 's':
        print('You lose!')
        losses = losses + 1
elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'r':
        print('You lose!')
        losses = losses + 1
```

please refer to this website, 'https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter2/', it is a book name 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'. As shown at the bottom of this content title named, "A SHORT, PROGRAM: ROCK, PAPER, SISSORS shows how to program rps game, and I put exactly same source code into the file editor from above website, but game does not work as expected on the interactive shell.

Comment: Looks like that this line is unreachable due to an indentation issue : `if playerMove=='r' ...`

Comment: Could you tell me line number please?

Comment: No I can't. Just after `sys.exit()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I make every condition to have proper indentation, but still it does not work well, and I do not know what to do...

Comment: Please edit your post with the new code.

Comment: I edit it with the new code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I follow your answer but it still has not changed at all.

Comment: Strange. I played RPS with the code from my answer. Just tested right now, copy-pasted and played. What's your editor/IDE ?

Comment: I put your answer, and it just got it. Thx you so much, and it did not work because of not having proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with a few changes to make it work.

Reindented some parts :

- parts of the code were unreachable : the player could never enter his move
- all the game logic was outside of the loop

Note the new position of `if playerMove == "r"` that is now at the same indentation level as `if playerMove == "q"`.

Replaced `randiant`() that doesn't exist with `randint()`.

Indentation is very important in Python because there are no characters to delimit blocks as brackets in other languages.

Control structures (if, elif, else) and loops depend on indentation.

```py
import random, sys

print("ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS")

# These variables keep track of the number of wins, losses, and ties.
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

while True:  # The main game loop.
    print("%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties" % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True:  # The player input loop.
        print("Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit")
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == "q":
            sys.exit()  # Quit the program.
        if playerMove == "r" or playerMove == "p" or playerMove == "s":
            break  # Break out of the player input loop.
        print("Type one of r, p, s, or q.")

    # Display what the player chose:
    if playerMove == "r":
        print("ROCK versus...")
    elif playerMove == "p":
        print("PAPER versus...")
    elif playerMove == "s":
        print("SCISSORS versus...")

    # Display what the computer chose:
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 3)
    if randomNumber == 1:
        computerMove = "r"
        print("ROCK")
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        computerMove = "p"
        print("PAPER")
    elif randomNumber == 3:
        computerMove = "s"
        print("SCISSORS")

    # Display and record the win/loss/tie:
    if playerMove == computerMove:
        print("It is a tie!")
        ties = ties + 1
    elif playerMove == "r" and computerMove == "s":
        print("You win!")
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == "p" and computerMove == "r":
        print("You win!")
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == "s" and computerMove == "p":
        print("You win!")
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == "r" and computerMove == "p":
        print("You lose!")
        losses = losses + 1
    elif playerMove == "p" and computerMove == "s":
        print("You lose!")
        losses = losses + 1
    elif playerMove == "s" and computerMove == "r":
        print("You lose!")
        losses = losses + 1
```